# How to assign output of multiple shell commmands to variable when using tee?

Tags: bash, variables, tee

I want to `tee` and get the results from multiple shell commands connected in the pipeline. I made a simple example to explain the point. Suppose I wanna count the numbers of 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

```
echo "abcaabbcabc" | tee >(tr -dc 'a' | wc -m) >(tr -dc 'b' | wc -m) >(tr -dc 'c' | wc -m) > /dev/null
```

Then I tried to assign the result from each count to a shell variable, but they all end up empty.

```
echo "abcaabbcabc" | tee >(A=$(tr -dc 'a' | wc -m)) >(B=$(tr -dc 'b' | wc -m)) >(C=$(tr -dc 'c' | wc -m)) > /dev/null && echo $A $B $C
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: The variables are being created in subshells, they don't exist in the original shell.

Comment: Instead of using multiple process substitutions, why don't you just use a single `awk` script that counts each character and prints all the counts?

Comment: I see. But is there a way to retrieve those variables?

Comment: it was just a simple example... what I'm doing is not counting the characters ;-)

Comment: Whatever you're doing, you can probably put it into a single script, rather than lots of separate `tee` process substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use files. They are the single most reliable solution. Any of the commands may need different time to run. There is no easy way to synchronize command redirections. Then most reliable way is to use a separate "entity" to collect all the data:

```
tmpa=$(mktemp) tmpb=$(mktemp) tmpc=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$tmpa" "$tmpb" "$tmpc"' EXIT

echo "abcaabbcabc" | 
     tee >(tr -dc 'a' | wc -m > "$tmpa") >(tr -dc 'b' | wc -m > "$tmpb") | 
     tr -dc 'c' | wc -m > "$tmpc"
A=$(<"$tmpa")
B=$(<"$tmpb")
C=$(<"$tmpc")

rm "$tmpa" "$tmpb" "$tmpc"
trap '' EXIT
```

Second way:

You can prepend the data from each stream with a custom prefix. Then sort all lines (basically, buffer them) on the prefix and then read them. The example script will generate only a single number from each process substitution, so it's easy to do:

```
read -r A B C < <(
  echo "abcaabbcabc" | 
  tee >(
    tr -dc 'a' | wc -m | sed 's/^/A /'
  ) >(
    tr -dc 'b' | wc -m | sed 's/^/B /'
  ) >(
    tr -dc 'c' | wc -m | sed 's/^/C /'
  ) >/dev/null |
  sort |
  cut -d' ' -f2 |
  paste -sd' '
)
echo A="$A" B="$B" C="$C"
```

Using temporary files with `flock` to synchronize the output of child processes could look like this:

```
tmpa=$(mktemp) tmpb=$(mktemp) tmpc=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm "$tmpa" "$tmpb" "$tmpc"' EXIT

echo "abcaabbcabc" | 
(
  flock 3
  flock 4
  flock 5

  tee >(
    tr -dc 'a' | wc -m | 
    { sleep 0.1; cat; } > "$tmpa"

    # unblock main thread
    flock -u 3
  ) >(
    tr -dc 'b' | wc -m | 
    { sleep 0.2; cat; } > "$tmpb"

    # unblock main thread
    flock -u 4
  ) >(
    tr -dc 'c' | wc -m | 
    { sleep 0.3; cat; } > "$tmpc"

    # unblock main thread
    flock -u 5
  ) >/dev/null

  # wait for subprocesses to finish
  # need to re-open the files to block on them
  (
    flock 3
    flock 4
    flock 5
  ) 3<"$tmpa" 4<"$tmpb" 5<"$tmpc"
) 3<"$tmpa" 4<"$tmpb" 5<"$tmpc"

A=$(<"$tmpa")
B=$(<"$tmpb")
C=$(<"$tmpc")

declare -p A B C
```

Comment: Curious, why set the `trap` only to manually remove the files and the trap later rather than just letting the trap handle removal.

Comment: When the sub-processes take longer to compute, the tmp files are still empty when trying to retrieve the values.

Comment: Indeed. For that you have to synchronize them. You could use `flock`. `flock` no temporary files and unlock them when finished. The "main" process wait in `flock` on all 3 files.

Comment: The solution with `flock` does not give any result. I guess it got trapped somewhere.

Comment: I tried to assign to each descriptor a lock file `exec 3>/var/tmp/testlock3.lock || exit 1` ... now it finishes execution, but the final values of variables A, B and C are all empty.

Comment: I put the example here http://tpcg.io/9O5fge   in my terminal I just get the last variable. A= B= C=6. I'm under GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). Strange.

Comment: I've downloaded bash-4.4.18 and it runs ok. :-s

Comment: And still another problem... If you increase the sleep time in one of the threads you won't get the result right. Increasing the first sleep to 5 seconds you'll get an empty A.   http://tpcg.io/9O5fge

Comment: You lock on different files. First you lock using `$locka`, then inside the command substitution the `$locka` is unlocked, but then the main process waits on `$tmpa` so there is no locking at all.  Either do all locks on `lock*` files or none of them...  http://tpcg.io/36Rxj5 or if you need to use separate files for locking like  http://tpcg.io/HwgfAi

Comment: Right. It just don't work on newer version of bash. Something changed or is it just a bug?

Comment: @LEo you are right with it doesn't seem to work on newest system.

Comment: @LEo The issue seems to be a bug and I can replicate it on any bashv5, while cannot on bash<4. I have created such oneliner: `timeout 1 bash -x -c 'touch /tmp/1; echo | ( flock 13; tee >(cat; echo "all ok"; flock -u 13) >/dev/null; ( flock 13 ) 13</tmp/1) 13</tmp/1' || echo "not ok"` to reproduce the issue. If it prints `not ok` - means the script timeouted and there is something not ok. I have reported it as a bug to bash-bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this featured letter frequency analysis

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A letter_frequency
while read -r v k; do
    letter_frequency[$k]="$v"
done < <(
  grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' <<<"abcaabbcabc" |
    sort |
      uniq -c
)
for k in "${!letter_frequency[@]}"; do
  printf '%c = %d\n' "$k" "${letter_frequency[$k]}"
done
```

Output:

```
c = 3
b = 4
a = 4
```

Or to only assign `$A`, `$B` and `$C` as in your example:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

{
  read -r A _
  read -r B _
  read -r C _
}< <(
  grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' <<<"abcaabbcabc" |
    sort |
      uniq -c
)
printf 'a=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d\n' "$A" "$B" "$C"
```

- `grep -o '[[:alnum:]]'`: split each alphanumeric character on its own line
- `sort`: sort lines of characters
- `uniq -c`: count each instance and output count and character for each
- `< <( command group; )`: the output of this command group is for stdin of the command group before

If you need to count occurrence of non-printable characters, newlines, spaces, tabs, you have to make all these commands output and deal with null delimited lists. It can sure be done with the GNU versions of these tools. I let it to you as an exercise.

---

Solution to the count arbitrary characters except null:

As demonstrated, works also with Unicode.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A character_frequency
declare -i v
while read -d '' -r -N 8 v && read -r -d '' -N 1 k; do
    character_frequency[$k]="$v"
done < <(
  grep --only-matching --null-data . <<<$'a¹bc✓   ✓\n\t\t\u263A☺ ☺   aabbcabc' |
    head --bytes -2 | # trim the newline added by grep
      sort --zero-terminated | # sort null delimited list
        uniq --count --zero-terminated # count occurences of char (null delim)
)
for k in "${!character_frequency[@]}"; do
  printf '%q = %d\n' "$k" "${character_frequency[$k]}"
done
```

Output:

```
$'\n' = 1
$'\t' = 2
☺ = 3
\  = 7
✓ = 2
¹ = 1
c = 3
b = 4
a = 4
```